# Filtering text using sed based on pattern starting with 2 characters and numbers

Tags: unix, sed, awk

I have a file that keeps changing format but it always contains a pattern that I need to retrieve.

Here are a few lines of the sample file:

```
1    PL000000002002695895        611         1/11/2013  
2    PL000000002002785424        359         7/11/2013  
3.-PL000000002002121651                               11                     DAY 24/11/2013
4.-PL000000002002343228                               43                     DAY 29/11/2013
5    PL000000002002232587          NEW   360         30/11/2013
```

I tried using these two commands to filter from the list #3 and #4, but I am still having problem retrieving the other fields.

Here are the commands I used:

```
awk 'substr($1,4,2) == "PL" {print substr($1,4)}' sample > sample2
```

The  command above does not filter for double digits at the beginning of a line.

```
awk '{print $1}' sample | sed 's/^[[:digit:]]*\.\-//g' > sample2
```

This one works but only for a special case.

Any help would be greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the output you want or not but it'll work with any sed on any OS:

```
$ cat file
1    PL000000002002695895        611         1/11/2013  
2    PL000000002002785424        359         7/11/2013  
3.-PL000000002002121651                               11                     DAY 24/11/2013
4.-PL000000002002343228                               43                     DAY 29/11/2013
5    PL000000002002232587          NEW   360         30/11/2013
$ 
$ sed 's/.*\(PL[0-9]*\).*/\1/' file
PL000000002002695895
PL000000002002785424
PL000000002002121651
PL000000002002343228
PL000000002002232587
```

If that's not what you're looking for, update your question with more representative input if necessary and definitely some expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just check for the presence of `PL` in the first field?

```
awk 'index($1, "PL")' sample > sample2
```

Comment: I tried using the awk index and it is not providing me with any results, I guess the unix box I use is completely outdated.

Comment: I guess I should have mentioned this since the very beginning, I am stuck using csh in this HP-UX box. I do not know if that helps, but I also tried using match and I do not have any results.

Comment: @sayayinx, how about `grep '^[^[:space:]]\+PL' sample`?

Comment: I am out of luck, using grep I received no output :(